# accessing folder inside .net core library

Tags: c#, file, .net-core

I am building a .netcore library.And testing it using .net core console application.
I have the following folder structure inside Library:

```
WrapperLib
 |->FolderXYZ
    |->FileABC.txt
 |->ControllerClass.cs
```

I am trying to access FileABC.txt from ControllerClass.cs using relative path "\FolderXYZ\FileABC.txt".
But when I run application using .net core console application, by default the program is taking running application's home directory as Current working directory. How can I solve this and give correct reference to FileABC.txt from ControllerClass.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
 var location = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "FolderXYZ\\FileABC.txt");
```

Also dont forget to set "**Copy to output directory**" to "Always" or "Copy if newer".

Alternatively you can set the "Build action" as "Embedded resource" (thus it will become part of your compiled assembly) and then read it using the stream like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file).